# Select a value and then update the value in same query in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-core

i want to get a value using select then use the value from select in a update statement in the same query.

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
cmd.Connection = connection;

cmd.CommandText = "Declare @appln_id int;set @appln_id=select APPLN_INST_ID from CP.USR_RQST where RQST_ID=@RI;" +
"Update CP.APPLN_INST set SCRN_SESS_DTA=@SSD where APPLN_INST_ID=@appln_id";                

cmd.Parameters.Add("@RI", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = res.RequestDetails.AssetCollectionRequest.RequestId;                
cmd.Parameters.Add("@SSD", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = somevalue;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@appln_id", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;                
connection.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I am getting a syntax error on the query.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
```

Comment: This looks like it should be done as a stored procedure

Comment: yes, it should be. I am just trying to use SET in C# code is that not possible ?

Comment: AFAIK no. But you don't need to. Either use a stored procedure or execute two separate commands (passing the result of the first one as a parameter to the second one)

Answer (score 1):

You didn’t declared @appln_id variable.

When you trying to assign value to a variable you must first declare it. I didn’t see declare keyword in your query.

For example; you put this to top your query. It means before Set command.

declare @appln_id INT; // int is data type of variable. You should change what you need.

Comment: Firstly, write the query clearly in below.

`code`
declare @appln_id INT;
set @appln_id = select APPLN_INST_ID from CP.USR_RQST where RQST_ID=@RI;

Update CP.APPLN_INST set SCRN_SESS_DTA=@SSD where APPLN_INST_ID=@appln_id;
`code`

then try the query in MSSQL Management Studio. I think the query is OK but you can't use properly in your C# code.

Comment: yes, can you point out the error in the c# code ? I have tried what you said it seems to throw the same error

Answer (score 1):

try

update CP.APPLN_INST set SCRN_SESS_DTA=@SSD where APPLN_INST_ID=(select APPLN_INST_ID from CP.USR_RQST where RQST_ID=@RI)

Comment: Yes, this would work but the intention of the question is how to use SET inside the query